# libdb4.6-dev vs libdb4.7-dev

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apxs2, ubuntu-8.10

I want to install PHP 5.3 on Ubuntu Intrepid.  To install apxs, I need to install libaprutil1-dev, which depends on libdb4.6-dev.  When I look at installing that, apt-get wants to remove the currently installed libdb-dev and libdb4.7-dev.  Any advice on how to proceed?

```
[root@server:/usr/local]
#> apt-get -s install libaprutil1-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

Since you only requested a single operation it is extremely likely that
the package is simply not installable and a bug report against
that package should be filed.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libaprutil1-dev: Depends: libdb4.6-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages

[root@server:/usr/local]
#> apt-get -s install libdb4.6-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  debhelper libltdl7-dev po-debconf intltool-debian libtool courier-ssl gettext libgdbm-dev libzip1 html2text autotools-dev libmail-sendmail-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  db4.6-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libdb-dev libdb4.7-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdb4.6-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 2 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
Remv libdb-dev [4.7.25.2ubuntu1]
Remv libdb4.7-dev [4.7.25-3]
Inst libdb4.6-dev (4.6.21-10 Ubuntu:8.10/intrepid)
Conf libdb4.6-dev (4.6.21-10 Ubuntu:8.10/intrepid)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like people haven't been updating their packages very well. Try adding these lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid universe multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
```

Then try running `sudo apt-get install <package name>/lucid`

EDIT: Just noticed you're on intrepid...sorry! This still might work though.